# What are the odds that this iPhone app will fail?

Tags: iphone, app-store

I've been waiting on an iPhone app to go through the app store approval process. It's been in the queue for about two weeks now.

Apple recently added something to the dev center about reachability, pointing developers to their sample app. In my app, I'm posting to a URL on my server using HTTP - but I'm not doing a reachability check first. If the user tries to submit the request, it will eventually time out and they will see an error.

What are the chances that Apple will fail this app? I'm wondering if I should just quickly implement reachability and "reject binary" myself, submitting a new version. Might save me a couple of days if I'm just going to get rejected anyway.

Comment: why would somebody vote for a close? It's a programming-related question that can be answered with "yes" or "no" by somebody with anecdotal evidence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement reachability, if your app uses the web and when there is no connectivity the app doesnt say something along the lines that "this is not working because you have no internet access" then 95 percent it will be rejected by apple

Comment: well, it passed. ;) but this is definitely a fix I want in for the next version.

Comment: lucky you :), apples approval process is really inconsistent

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you answered your own question to me - not handling that case is a serious UX problem you should definitely fix.

Comment: Agreed. This is precisely the kind of thing I would actually WANT Apple to reject.

Comment: Not really, the question was whether or not you guys think it will be approved. Not whether what I did was "right" or "wrong." There's always room for version 1.1

Comment: @bpapa the great thing about Stackoverflow is you can get that extra feedback without even having to ask for it

Answer (score 0):

If I were expecting to deal with a reasonable, smart approval process, I would do exactly that -- fix the app to match their new documents. It's a classy move, implying you'd be a good citizen.

You may want to rely on someone who's been through the iPhone app store, though, for an answer with the right amount of cynicism.